# Getting duplicate class found error when merging two applications projects

Tags: android, tensorflow

Error when merging two application projects.

```
Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.DataType found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-1.13.1-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.13.1) and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)
Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.DataType$1 found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-1.13.1-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.13.1) and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)
Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.Delegate found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-1.13.1-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.13.1) and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)
Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-1.13.1-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.13.1) and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey for my case the error was "`Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.TensorOperatorWrapper found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-support-0.1.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0) and jetified-tensorflow-lite-support-api-0.4.4-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support-api:0.4.4)`"

Solution
I commented in the build.gradle the below dependency and it worked fine. `//implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'`

My Opinions
On your case you might need to comment one of your dependencies that have the version mentioned in the error you received such as "`(org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.13.1) and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)`"

When done, Sync and rebuild the project again.Hope you find this helpful.